# unable to connect ethernet on manjaro linux

Tags: ethernet, manjaro

I am installed Manjaro Linux 15.09 which is based on Arch Linux, but Ethernet is not working, although WIFI is.
How can I solve this problem?

Information of my system:

[output of lspci](http://sprunge.us/IdBW)
Output of `uname -r`: `4.1.8-1-MANJARO`
[output of lsusb](http://sprunge.us/bfaF)

Please tell me if you need more information...

my laptop is = Lenovo Z50-70, but **Ethernet works fine on Ubuntu 15.10**

Comment: Ethernet seems pretty much standard...what is the brand of the machine?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Lenovo Z50-70, but ethernet works fine on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: I asked that because Lenovo, HP and Dell are know to rebranding and giving different vendor IDs to some cards. It might not have anything to do with it, but google about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the package in `extra` repo of Manjaro Linux called `linux41-r8168` for R8168 driver

```
pacman -S linux41-r8168
```

Comment: That is a Manjaro package, not an Arch Linux one (so, no, it *isn't* in the Arch [extra] repository).

Comment: @jasonwryan better?